# maven-antrun-plugin does not execute script on Linux if parameterized

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I've got some weird case where the maven-antrun-plugin does not execute a script if its set into a property (and inside a maven profile).

This version does not execute the script (no errors what so ever):

```
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <condition property="buildScript" value="b2e-build-sonar.bat" else="b2e-build-sonar.sh">
                                    <os family="windows"/>
                                </condition>

                                <chmod file="${project.basedir}/${buildScript}" perm="ugo+rx"/>

                                <echo>Starting Grunt build in ${project.basedir} using ${buildScript}</echo>

                                <exec executable="${project.basedir}/${buildScript}" failonerror="true" output="antrun-sonar.log" spawn="false" failifexecutionfails="true">
                                    <env key="SONAR_HOST" value="${sonar.host.url}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_URL" value="${sonar.jdbc.url}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME" value="${sonar.jdbc.username}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD" value="${sonar.jdbc.password}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_SCM_URL" value="${project.scm.connection}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_PROJECT_KEY" value="${project.artifactId}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_PROJECT_VERSION" value="${project.version}" />
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The echo message is shown correctly.
The exec ist just not happening.
The same task on windows works well.

So I changed the configuration to:

```
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <chmod file="${project.basedir}/b2e-build-sonar.sh" perm="ugo+rx"/>

                                <echo>Starting Grunt build in ${project.basedir} (Unix Only)</echo>

                                <exec executable="${project.basedir}/b2e-build-sonar.sh" failonerror="true" osfamily="unix">
                                    <env key="SONAR_HOST" value="${sonar.host.url}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_URL" value="${sonar.jdbc.url}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME" value="${sonar.jdbc.username}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD" value="${sonar.jdbc.password}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_SCM_URL" value="${project.scm.connection}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_PROJECT_KEY" value="${project.artifactId}" />
                                    <env key="SONAR_PROJECT_VERSION" value="${project.version}" />
                                </exec>

                                <echo>ANT execution done.</echo>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

mainly calling the script directly without the condition. This does execute the script on linux as well.

Why is the same script as a property not working on unix (but does on windows)?

Thanks!